# why is my react app displaying a download icon in browser address bar that says "Install Create React App Sample"?

Tags: reactjs

Any idea why my React app may be displaying a download icon in browser address bar that says "Install Create React App Sample"?  I don't think I've ever seen this behavior before and not sure what is causing that to display.  That's not the intended behavior of course.  Have you ever seen this behavior before?  Any idea what the root cause might be or how to prevent this from displaying?  Screenshot attached

[image]

Comment: Your browser is thinking your web app is a PWA.

Answer (score 2):

Hello I also had this problem; Apparently is because your browser thinks that you are using a Progressive Web App.
Deleting the "name" field of the "manifest.json" from your "public/" directory should solve the problem, however first please check the link I share.
The full response of what I found:

[Link here](https://www.reddit.com/r/reactjs/comments/143566t/why_is_my_react_app_displaying_a_download_icon_in/)

Have a nice day.